# overriding startResolutionForResult's dialog

Tags: android, google-play-services

enter image description here Is there anyway to override the google play services dialog returned from `startResolutionForResult()`. I am using this from the location settings api. It launches a dialog when the location is off.

It currently has a negative, neutral and positive button. What I want is to remove this negative button.

Actual dialog:

[image: Actual image]

expected dialog:

[image: Expected image]

Comment: did you get any solution? If yes, can you please answer your question? I am facing a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for every one who is facing the same problem, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872703/1320263). You need to add the  `builder.setAlwaysShow(true);` before you do the `checkLocationSettings`