# Use the Android Default GPS ON-OFF dialog in My application

Tags: android, gps, action, android-alertdialog

In Our application we want to integrate the android Default GPS Dialog. The same dialog that appears when the GPS is OFF and we press of my location button in google map apps. Have also attached the image of the dialog which I want to integrate.

1. Clicking on "No" option will close the dialog.
2. Clicking on "Yes" option will Activate the GPS of device directly.

Dialog the appears for OLA app Below (ANDROID L):
[image]

Dialog the appears for OLA app Below (ANDROID KIT_KAT):
[image]

Dialog the appears for Google Map Below (ANDROID L):
[image]

Our existing implementation is when the GPS is OFF we are redirecting application to the default location setting screen of the device from where he/she can turn ON the Location.

looking forward for answers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think  you have to create custom dialog which is allow to ON/OFF in lollipop through ur control.

Comment: I've seen the same dialog in OLA cab application. I don't think that they have created the custom Dialog. whats your thoughts. Same appear for KIT-KAT version to.

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps

Comment: @Balu having same issue. Please help me if you got the your nswer

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi: Is it still pending.  Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the latest version of Google Play service. latest version has one dialog to activate all required things to get the GPS.

From Android Developer Play Service documentation,

> Location settings - While the FusedLocationProviderApi combines multiple sensors to give you the optimal location, the accuracy of the location your app receives still depends greatly on the settings enabled on the device (GPS, wifi, airplane mode, and others). Using the new SettingsApi class, you can bring up a Location Settings dialog which displays a one-touch control for users to change their settings without leaving your app.

[Link](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html#) directs to Play Service version documentation. Version 7.0 has introduced this new prompt.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede deprecated! use this instead https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;

public class LocSettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback {

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected LocationRequest locationRequest;
    int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loc_settings);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
        PendingResult result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        builder.build()
                );

        result.setResultCallback(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                // NO need to show the dialog;

                break;

            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                //  Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog

                try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                    // in onActivityResult().

                    status.startResolutionForResult(LocSettingsActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);

                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                    //failed to show
                }
                break;

            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                // Location settings are unavailable so not possible to show any dialog now
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}
```