# Android runtime permissions on android versions below M?

Tags: android, gps, android-location, android-permissions

[image: Runtime Android permissions]

Recently my [ola cabs application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiKMH.jpg), after the latest update, asked for location permission at runtime. It did not open the location settings screen but just by clicking on yes, my location (GPS) of the device was turned on and the application proceeded without going to location settings or any settings screen. This feature was about to come in android M and is available on the MNC preview only, so I am guessing it cannot be used in devices at this point of time. So how is this application implementing this feature?

Comment: Might be requesting precise location, when you had GPS disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [using `SettingsApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi) in the Play Services SDK 7.0+, to [display the location settings dialog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html).

Comment: @gopi1410: FWIW, here is a sample app demonstrating its use, as part of getting periodic locations from the fused location provider: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Location/FusedPeriodic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093673/use-the-android-default-gps-on-off-dialog-in-my-application/37246593#37246593 full code