# Turn on the GPS on automatically like OLA cabs app

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to turn on the gps automatically. But I can not find the solution for this. Now I am using like navigate to the settings page to turn on the GPS. In OLA cabs app gps is automatically on. I want to turn on the GPS location automatically like OLA cabs. I am using following code for switch on the GPS.

```
public void MessageNoGps(final Activity mActivity) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
        builder.setMessage(mActivity.getString(R.string.gps_enable))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(mActivity.getString(R.string.yes),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                    final int id) {
                                mActivity
                                        .startActivity(new Intent(
                                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(mActivity.getString(R.string.no),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                    final int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                                mActivity.finish();
                            }
                        });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Please let me know how to turn on the GPS automatically.

Comment: @1615903.. Thanks for sharing the link. But how OLA activate the GPS?

Comment: Ok, just checked the Ola Cabs app - maybe you are looking for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps