# Is there a way to detect Location is OFF on Android Wear Watch as opposed to not present

Tags: android, wear-os, android-gps

I have developed a Referee Watch (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pipperpublishing.soccerrefpro) which tracks referees field coverage and other fitness stats using the watch GPS. This is NOT a question about ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions which I am handling just fine.

I understand I can use `getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS`to determine if the Watch has GPS. However, if a user accidentally turns OFF Settings>Location on the Watch, is there a way of detecting it? I suspect the watch will report TRUE for the above call, but then attempt to deliver location using the Fused Location Provider from the phone wifi/gps/cell. That of course is useless once you are running on the field with the phone in the bag.

I have tried looking at the Fitness Sensor sources and determining whether the source is Local or not, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already determined whether your Android Wear device has a built-in GPS sensor using the `hasSystemFeature()` method, then you can proceed with [handling disconnection events](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/wear-location-detection.html#Disconnection).

You may want to implement [`onPeerDisconnected()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService#onPeerDisconnected(com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node)) method so that your app should be able to handle loss of location data in case the wear device loses connection with its paired device.

Also, check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068797/android-wear-detect-if-handheld-gps-is-enabled-prompt-to-enable-if-not) for additonal insights on how to trigger a system UI to get that permission to enable location dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I'll take a look!