# Can i change dailog style which let user to enable location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I want to change the style of dialog which appear by google-service-lib
and let user press yes or no then location open without go to location setting
can i do it ? this link have example to this dialog if i can how can i change it
[How to show enable location dialog like Google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps/29872703#29872703)

Comment: Just make your custom dialog

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's a code snippet on how to [Create a Dialog Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html):

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Other samples:

- [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)
- [Coding Android Custom Dialogs the easy way](http://www.101apps.co.za/articles/coding-android-custom-dialogs-the-easy-way.html)

Comment: no man i no need how to create custom dialog i want to modify location dialog