# SettingsApi dialog "never" option ignored

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-location

I'm using SettingsApi to show this dialog if location settings are not properly configured. It work fine on most phones, but some users are reporting a problem with the "Never" option. Even when they press Never, the dialog still appears on next launch.

I've been debugging my code, but everything appears to work fine (well, at least my devices).
This is the code I'm using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872703

1. What could be the problem?
2. Is there a way to maybe intercept Never option and save this to the SharedPreferences?

   [image]

EDIT: The problem is on all Android versions, not just M.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719047/android-m-check-runtime-permission-how-to-determine-if-the-user-checked-nev

Comment: The problem isn't with permissions, those work fine. I think my problem is unrelated to M permissions.

Comment: Can you mention specific devices encountering this?