# How to customize "enable location" dialog in android?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

For a location aware app that i am developing, i need to start the GPS programatically, but after a lot of research i found that, this is no longer allowed in newer versions of android (yes, there are some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android), but they exploit some bugs in android- not a solid solution). so i use the enable location dialog (it is way much better than redirecting  the user to settings page, to enable the GPS).

As you can see in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps), i want to customize the looks of this dialog with a custom layout to make it look like the rest of my app.

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: Nope.............

Comment: I'm asking because I write my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53387741/strange-behavior-of-locationrequest-priorities), and I think the bug that I found depend on default layout of dialog...