# Programmatically Location does not turn on even after clicking yes on prompt

Tags: android, android-location

I am Making an App where we send user location on Server by using Api basically flow is when user launch an app after sometimes location prompt will popup and when user selects yes after that another code block will be implmented after 30 seconds by using Runnable Method. Everything is working fine only problem is after click yes Location Service is not starting I have to manually turn it on and after turning it on I am able to send lat long.Need some advice on this issue This is what I have tried till now. Thank you in advance!

LocationTrack.java

```
public class LocationTrack extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;


    boolean checkGPS = false;
    boolean checkNetwork = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location loc;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;


    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public LocationTrack(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        getLocation();
    }

    private Location getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // get GPS status
//            checkGPS = locationManager
//                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // get network provider status
            checkNetwork = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!checkNetwork) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Service Provider is available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;



                if (checkNetwork) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    }

                    if (loc != null) {
                        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return loc;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (loc != null) {
            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (loc != null) {
            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

//    public void showSettingsAlert() {
//        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
//
//
//        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is not Enabled!");
//
//        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to turn on GPS?");
//
//
//        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//
//            }
//        });
//
//
//        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                dialog.cancel();
//            }
//        });
//
//
//        alertDialog.show();
//    }


    public void stopListener() {
        if (locationManager != null) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationTrack.this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String url = "API";
    String androidId, uuid;
    String deviceDetails;

    //location variables
    double latitude, longitude, lng, lat;
    private ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest;
    private ArrayList<String> permissionsRejected = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

    private final static int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;
    LocationTrack locationTrack;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //location Permission
        permissions.add(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        permissions.add(ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);


        askLocation();


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //device details
                androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                getDeviceDetails();


                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("CODE", "================================");
                        Log.i("Response", response);
                        Log.i("CODE", "================================");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.i("CODE", "================================");
                        Log.i("Error", String.valueOf(error));
                        Log.i("CODE", "================================");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
//                if (locationTrack.canGetLocation()) {
//
//
//                    lng = locationTrack.getLongitude();
//                    lat = locationTrack.getLatitude();
//
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude:" + Double.toString(longitude) + "\nLatitude:" + Double.toString(latitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }

                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("lat", String.valueOf(lng));
                        params.put("lng", String.valueOf(lat));
                        params.put("android_id", androidId);
                        params.put("uuid", uuid);
                        params.put("device_details", deviceDetails);
                        return params;
                    }
                };

                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(request);
            }
        }, 30000);
    }

    @SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    public void getDeviceDetails() {

        deviceDetails = "SERIAL : " + Build.SERIAL + " , " +
                "MODEL: " + Build.MODEL + " , " +
                "ID: " + Build.ID + " , " +
                "Manufacture: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " , " +
                "Brand: " + Build.BRAND + " , " +
                "SDK: " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + " , " +
                "Version Code: " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successful" + deviceDetails, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //location methods
    private ArrayList<String> findUnAskedPermissions(ArrayList<String> wanted) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String perm : wanted) {
            if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
                result.add(perm);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        if (canMakeSmores()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean canMakeSmores() {
        return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT) {
            for (String perms : permissionsToRequest) {
                if (!hasPermission(perms)) {
                    permissionsRejected.add(perms);
                }
            }

            if (permissionsRejected.size() > 0) {


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionsRejected.get(0))) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("These permissions are mandatory for the application. Please allow access.",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermissions(permissionsRejected.toArray(new String[0]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    private void askLocation() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0)
                requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[0]), ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
        }

        locationTrack = new LocationTrack(MainActivity.this);


        if (locationTrack.canGetLocation()) {


            longitude = locationTrack.getLongitude();
            latitude = locationTrack.getLatitude();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude:" + (longitude) + "\nLatitude:" + (latitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

//            locationTrack.showSettingsAlert();
            longitude = locationTrack.getLongitude();
            latitude = locationTrack.getLatitude();
        }
        lat = latitude;
        lng = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        locationTrack.stopListener();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is already answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46385161/1337664

Google keeps changing the APIs for this stuff, so you will need multiple ways depending on how many older versions of Android you want to support.