# Android Fused Location Update

Tags: android, android-location, android-maps, android-fusedlocation

I am developing an android application and I am fetching device current location by Fused Location.

I am checking if a user has grant permission or not if yes I am fetching location but If a user has not granted the permission I am opening permission dialog box and a user clicks on allow then google is showing following dialog box:

[image]

How should I handle this dialog box click event because what is happing if a user clicks on OK but it's not fetching device location or I am not getting any location update callback? I want when user click on OK it should fetch location.
How should I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show enable location dialog like Google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps)

Comment: Location setting popup will give callback result by calling onActivityResult(), So you have to implement onActivityResult in activity. For example refer 
(https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient).

Answer (score 0):

```
     publi void myLocationButtonClicked(){

GpsLocationTracker mGpsLocationTracker = new GpsLocationTracker(activity);
                if (mGpsLocationTracker.canGetLocation()) {

                    latitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLatitude();
                    longitude = mGpsLocationTracker.getLongitude();

    if ((latitude != 0 && longitude != 0)
     } else {
                        showLocationSnackBar(activity.getString(R.string.wait));
                    }
                } else {
                    locationChecker();
                }
      // this function to show dialog to open GPS if it is closed

     public void locationChecker() {


            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

            SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity);
            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

            task.addOnSuccessListener(activity, locationSettingsResponse -> myLocationButtonClicked());

            task.addOnFailureListener(activity, e -> {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(activity,
                                REQUEST_GPS_RESULT_CODE_FOR_MAP_LOCATION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

this is the `GpsLocationTracker` class to fetch user location

```
public class GpsLocationTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    /**
     * min distance change to get location update
     */
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
    /**
     * min time for location update
     * 60000 = 1min
     */
    private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 60000;
    /**
     * context of calling class
     */
    private Context mContext;
    /**
     * flag for gps status
     */
    private boolean isGpsEnabled = false;
    /**
     * flag for network status
     */
    private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    /**
     * flag for gps
     */
    private boolean canGetLocation = false;
    /**
     * location
     */
    private Location mLocation;
    /**
     * latitude
     */
    private double mLatitude;
    /**
     * longitude
     */
    private double mLongitude;
    /**
     * location manager
     */
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;


    /**
     * @param mContext constructor of the class
     */
    public GpsLocationTracker(Context mContext) {

        this.mContext = mContext;
        getLocation();
    }


    /**
     * @return location
     */
    public Location getLocation() {

        try {

            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            /*getting status of the gps*/
            isGpsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            /*getting status of network provider*/
            isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

                /*no location provider enabled*/
            } else {

                this.canGetLocation = true;

                /*getting location from network provider*/
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE, this);

                    if (mLocationManager != null) {

                        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (mLocation != null) {

                            mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();

                            mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                    /*if gps is enabled then get location using gps*/
                    if (isGpsEnabled) {

                        if (mLocation == null) {

                            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE, this);

                            if (mLocationManager != null) {

                                mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                                if (mLocation != null) {

                                    mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();

                                    mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mLocation;
    }

    /**
     * call this function to stop using gps in your application
     */
    public void stopUsingGps() {

        if (mLocationManager != null) {

            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(GpsLocationTracker.this);

        }
    }

    /**
     * @return latitude
     * <p/>
     * function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {

        if (mLocation != null) {

            mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
        }
        return mLatitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return longitude
     * function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {

        if (mLocation != null) {

            mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();

        }

        return mLongitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return to check gps or wifi is enabled or not
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {

        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * function to prompt user to open
     * settings to enable gps
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {

        AlertDialog.Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, R.style.AppTheme));

        mAlertDialog.setTitle(R.string.gps_disabled);

        mAlertDialog.setMessage(R.string.enable_gps);

        mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
            }
        });

        mAlertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_button_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });


        final AlertDialog mcreateDialog = mAlertDialog.create();
        mcreateDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

and when user click ok button the you have to check                      the result in `onActivityResult()`.

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_GPS_RESULT_CODE_FOR_MAP_LOCATION && resultCode == RESULT_OK)


myLocationButtonClicked();
        }
```

Comment: but where is ok button click listener as @Harsh Shah asking question... can you explain your answer

Comment: I am doing the same but I am not getting any callback  onActivityResult

Comment: are you in activity or fragment ?

Comment: i think we can't handle this dialog ok button click because its internally only enable your GPS but after click on ok button you get a status code i am sharing a answer try this too, in that code i handle status code if gsp enable or not a status code is maintained let me share...

Comment: @HiteshKushwah Ok. Waiting for your answer

Comment: But i am not confirm it will solving your problem or not you can try my code may be it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Try this Function call this function on button click listner and disable your gps.. and when you clicking on button gps dialog will appear and gps enable and when again you clicking on button toast will show that handle by status code

```
    private void EnableGPSAutoMatically() {
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = null;
        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
            googleApiClient.connect();
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            // **************************
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true); // this is the key ingredient
            // **************************

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi
                    .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    final LocationSettingsStates state = result
                            .getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            toast("Success");

                            isgpson = true;
                            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                            // initialize location
                            // requests here.
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
//                            toast("GPS is not on");
                            isgpson  = false;
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be
                            // fixed by showing the user
                            // a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling
                                // startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                status.startResolutionForResult(Activity_Splash.this, 1000);

                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
//                            toast("Setting change not allowed");
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have
                            // no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```