# Can be native dialog (e.g. fused location enable) somehow forced to have light theme even though dark theme is set?

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

Basically I have an application which does have only light scheme and I want to ensure/force that native fused location enable dialog will be white even though the phone is for example in dark mode. Code was taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796199/5969676)

Code:

```
LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task= LocationServices.getSettingsClient(eTicketActivity).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.

                } catch (ApiException exception) {
                    switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                            // user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                        MainActivity.this,
                                        101;
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

which looks like this:
[image: resulting fused location dialog]

So question is, can be light theme of dialog achieved even though the whole phone is in dark mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of *Map SDK* and all Google stuffs get theme from Android System Setting and you can not customize it.